# Is there any way to Update a List item at Run time

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-core-webapi

I am very new to .net core api. I got one assessment to create few get and a put operation for below requirement.
They have Company, ClaimType and Claims table. Data has to be generated from code (not from database). I am struggling with the PUT operation.
As I can't use database, I created Lists for Company, ClaimType and Claims and initialised them.

I have the below List<> -

```
 public static List<ClaimType> claimTypes = new List<ClaimType>
     {
         new ClaimType {Id = 1, Name = "Type1"},
         new ClaimType {Id = 2, Name = "Type2"},
         new ClaimType {Id = 3, Name = "Type3"}
     };
```

So, like updating database, I want to update this List<> at run time for any specific Id. For example, if someone updated Name = "Abc for ClaimTypeId = 2. Then I want this list to be replaced.

Currently it's not updating. Is there any way to do this or any suggestion on how to approach this assessment without using database.

Comment: So you acces by key, right? Are you _sure_ you do not want a `Dictionary<int, ClaimType>` instead? Is this used in a multithreaded fashion?

Comment: _"Then I want this list to be replaced."_ - What _exactly_ does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
var claim= claimTypes.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == 2);
if(claim != null){
    claim.Name = "Abc";
}
```